# Zoom effect flicking

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm working on a personal site, and i made this simple effect on the left and right sides. But when i put the mouse on the right side and go back to the left side, this flick happens and idk how to fix this. Its not a problem, but its too ugly and i want to make this effect to be smooth

Here a gif showing the flick

[Idk if its possible to see in the gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifAFN.gif)

Here my CSS code

```
.Container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
}

.ChoseContainer {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 300%;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}

.Text {
  margin-top: 70vh;
}

.Title {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size: 600%;
  margin-top: 15vh;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  color: aliceblue;
  z-index: 99;
}

.ChoseContainer:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

The class object is ChoseContainer and its inside of Container.

Expecting to make this effect to be smooth and not flicking anymore

Comment: Please make a snippet which shows the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Not even all the needed CSS is present in your question. Please edit it and add the CSS and HTML. You leave us guessing now.

Comment: When you transform the element it's changing size and this will cause this affect. The correction may just be to set .Container to have overflow:hidden. Possibly a few more fixes needed.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve a smoother zoom effect without flickering, modify your CSS like this:

```
.Container {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
}

.ChoseContainer {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 300%;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease;
  transform-origin: center center;
}

.ChoseContainer:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

It smoothly scales the ChoseContainer from its center when hovered over, creating a better zoom effect without flickering. You can adjust the scaling factor (1.1) to control the strength of the zoom effect.

Comment: Can you create a working example of this smoother scrolling? Note that `ease` might no be what is wanted or what will help with this problem.